# NSURLConnection fails after upgrade to iOS 5

Tags: xcode, ios5

I have a very simple NSURLConnection call that works perfectly in all iOS versions except iOS 5.  Since this is a 'sendSynchronousRequest' call, there are no NSURL delegates declared anywhere in the app (the response should come directly back to this method call).  Also, because this is a sendSynchronousRequest, there are no 'didReceiveData' or other NSURL-associated methods implemented in the app.

Here is the offending line of code:

```
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: serviceRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

When I step through the code in the debugger, I can confirm that app is sending the request, and that the server is receiving the request.  I can also confirm that the server is then sending a response back to the client.

This was all working perfectly until I upgraded to iOS 5.  Now, after the update to iOS5, the NSData variable (response) is never receiving anything and always comes back with 0 bytes.

Other than the update to iOS5, there have been no code changes at all.

Comment: Have you tried it with a dummy returningResponse parameter? The class reference doesn't say that this parameter may be NULL (other than the error). Or maybe it's already in Apple's known bugs list.

Comment: In my app, I actually don't use the nil parameter for the returningResponse or the error.  The full code that I'm using is:


    NSURLResponse *serviceResponse = nil;
    NSError *serviceError = nil;


 NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: serviceRequest returningResponse: &serviceResponse error: &serviceError];


If I check the NSError after the call is made, it is null.  If I check the NSURLResponse like this:

     NSLog(@"serviceResponse = %@", [serviceResponse URL]);

It will show me the URL of the server that I contacted.

Comment: Your sample code runs successfully on my iOS5 simulator.  If you post a more complete code example maybe we could replicate the problem you're having.

Answer (score 2):

There were several changes made to the NSURLConnection class in iOS 5. In particular, several delegate methods that were deprecated. I experienced a similar issue and it was caused by one of the delegate methods no longer being called. If this sounds like your issue, take a look at the formal delegate protocols `NSURLConnectionDelegate` and `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using a custom Web server. The problem turned out to be an invalid header in the response. I changed:

HTTP/1.1 200/OK

to:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

iOS 5 now accepts the response. Check your packet capture. You may have the same or similar problem.