# NSURLConnection in iOS5

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4, nsurlconnection, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I am using NSURLConnection for accessing webservices.

I am getting proper response in iOS 4.3 but If I run the same code in iOS5 I am getting NULL response.

What are the changes do I need to make to the existing NSURLConnection delegates to work successfully.

I have implemented NSURLConnectionDataDelegate & NSURLConnectionDelegate. Even then its not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you hitting the same link in both the version? or they are different in any means?

Comment: No. dey r same!! I jus changed the simulator version from iOS4.3 to iOS5 simulator

Answer (score 0):

You have some changes with `NSURLConnection` class in iOS 5 (some delegate methods are now deprecated).

You can find a good post about it here : [NSUrlConnection Class Changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785180/nsurlconnection-fails-after-upgrade-to-ios-5)